# How To Format Tooltip Text

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I have some code that needs formatting. Basically, I have some Highchart graphs with a rollover and that rollover displays a box with weather information inside it as shown here:

[image]

I want to make the values as shown the same style as the rest of the tooltip instead of displaying in bold. Here is the code responsible:

```
tooltip: {
        shared: true,
        crosshairs: true,
        valueSuffix: '°' + config.temp.units,
        valueDecimals: config.temp.decimals,
        xDateFormat: "%A, %e %b, %H:%M",
    },
```

Comment: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#tooltip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can edit [pointFormat](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#tooltip.pointFormat) and use line without `<b>` tags.

Output

```
 <span style="color:{point.color}">\u25CFÂ</span> {series.name}: {point.y}<br/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may refer to [HighCharts Tooltip formatter](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#tooltip) and you can add in your own CSS using `style`:

```
tooltip: {
    shared: true,
    crosshairs: true,
    valueSuffix: '°' + config.temp.units,
    valueDecimals: config.temp.decimals,
    xDateFormat: "%A, %e %b, %H:%M",
    style: {
        font-weight: "bold"
    }
},
```